# Defining styles by value from a map function

Tags: react-native

Hi i am new to React Native and i want to assign styles by index value returns from a map function but i am not able,I tried many ways but failed to get the desired output.The problem where i get stuck is styles are in object and what my solution is returns a string

```
        {Array(5)
          .fill()
          .map((page, i) => {
            return (
              <View key={i} style={`styles.screen${i}`}>
                <Text
                  style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 200, fontWeight: "900" }}
                >
                  {i}
                </Text>
              </View>
            );
          })}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen0: {
    width,
    height,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
  screen1: {
    width,
    height,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "gold",
  },
  screen2: {
    width,
    height,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "pink",
  },
  screen3: {
    width,
    height,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "pink",
  },
  screen4: {
    width,
    height,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
  },
});
```

Comment: Post more code on how your styles object looks like, so can help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this

```
{Array(5)
          .fill()
          .map((page, i) => {
            return (
              <View key={i} style={styles[`screen${i}`]}>
                <Text
                  style={{ color: "white", fontSize: 200, fontWeight: "900" }}
                >
                  {i}
                </Text>
              </View>
            );
          })}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the styles from within the style prop you have to do it like this =>

```
style={`${styles.screen${i}`}
```